# Set TTL to millions of Couchbase Documents

Tags: nosql, couchbase

I have a Couchbase 4.5.1 bucket with millions of documents, which do not have an expiration time. Is there a way to put TTL with a N1QL query, REST api or something?
I have not found a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the full list of document keys using N1QL (SELECT META().id FROM mybucket;) and then SET the TTL for each document using KV API.

You can't set the TTL via N1QL.